Problem connecting second external monitor
Computer: GIGABYTE G5 MF5 LAPTOP
I currently have 1 external monitor connected directly with an HDMI cable, I need to connect a second external monitor, I have tried connecting them to the C port, I have used several USB C to HDMI adapters, without success, it does not recognize the monitor.
I have tried with a mini DP to DP cable, without success.
I have checked the graphics card drivers, everything is in order.
It simply does not recognize.
I have disconnected the first monitor but it does not identify the USB C or mini DP port either.
It only directly recognizes the HDMI port but I need independent screens.
Port specifications:
2x USB 3.2 gen 2 port (type c)
– 1x mini DP 1.4
Thanks for your help!

What BIOS version are you running? According to Gigabyte site their was a BIOS release in Jan 2024 with a description of "miniDP compatability update": https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/G5--2023/support#support-dl-bios
